# В rails-проекте нет текста

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Попробую подробно объяснить суть проблемы, с которой недавно столкнулся. По учебнику писал простой интернет-магазин. Без дизайна, с голыми кнопками и полями ввода все было нормально. Но когда я начал работу по выделению цветом, то что-то пошло не так - описания выкладываемых товаров не было видно, точнее, их просто не существовало.

Порядок моей работы.

1. Сначала внес изменения в файл *seeds* - точнее, просто скопировал их с [сайта учебника](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/rails40/depot_a/db/seeds.rb) и вставил.
2. Затем я поработал с языком *SASS*, в файле `depot/app/assets/stylesheets/products.css.scss`, написав следующее:

   ```
   /* START_HIGHLIGHT */
   .products {
     table {
       border-collapse: collapse;
     }

     table tr td {
       padding: 5px;
       vertical-align: top;
     }

     .list_image {
       width:  60px;
       height: 70px;
     }

     .list_description {
       width: 60%;

       dl {
         margin: 0;
       }

       dt {
         color:        #244;
         font-weight:  bold;
         font-size:    larger;
       }

       dd {
         margin: 0;
       }
     }

     .list_actions {
       font-size:    x-small;
       text-align:   right;
       padding-left: 1em;
     }

     .list_line_even {
       background:   #e0f8f8;
     }

     .list_line_odd {
       background:   #f8b0f8;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Файл в директории `/depot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` ([вот он](http://pastebin.com/Ee8na84u)) я изменил четвертую с конца строку (с `<body>` на то, что имеется сейчас).

Comment: Я думаю уместнее задать этот вопрос на ресурсе урока. Маловероятно, что тут кто-то в теме всех деталей происходящего. Информации крайне мало.

Comment: «откатывайте» пошагово внесённые вами изменения, пока данные не «вернутся назад». это позволит локализовать вашу (или писателей учебника) ошибку. а вообще, конечно, надо было обращаться к первоисточнику.

Comment: Скажите, на какую страницу вашего интернет-магазина вы заходите? Если на `localhost:3000/products`, то пришлите содержимое файла `app/views/products/index.html.erb`.

Comment: Что значит "не существовало"? этот код, что рельсами не отрисовывался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте «откатывать» пошагово все внесённые вами изменения, пока данные не «вернутся назад».

это позволит локализовать вашу (или автора учебника) ошибку.

а вообще, конечно, стоило бы обратиться к первоисточнику: автору учебника.